# In a Processing method how to pass array as parameter, and how to return an array

Tags: arrays, parameters

In a Processing method, is it possible to pass an array as a parameter, and also to return an array as the result? If the answer is "yes", some simple examples would be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I continued to look into this, guessing at what might work, and found that this does:

```
String[] x = {"abc","def","gh","ijklmn"};
println(a(x)); 

String[] a(String[] y)
{ String b[] = y;
  return b;
}
```

Nicely shows

```
abc def gh ijklmn
```

in the lower Text Area

I will accept this as an answer when allowed, unless someone comes up with a better one.